# I need to know how to create dynamic response code in php

Tags: php, dynamic, response

All I know is that I need to create "201 Created" code with an xml reply. I am trying to reprduce an escl/AirScan response. I only have info gleaned from the web and little to test with

I think it needs to look something like this

```
header("HTTP/1.1 201 Created");
echo '<PageState>PreparingScan</PageState> 
<BinaryURL>/eSCL/Scans/'.$Name.'.'.$ext.'</BinaryURL>';

// i tried this, but this does not create new reply only appends the previous document 

ob_flush();
flush();

// here is code that takes some time

///after executing it needs to change to this

header("HTTP/1.1 201 Created");
echo '<PageState>ReadyToUpload</PageState> 
<BinaryURL>/eSCL/Scans/'.$Name.'.'.$ext.'</BinaryURL>';
```

So what I need is two different response codes generted 
from same page. One when it starts the action and another when it is done.
Doing as I have it here is crashing the client, and confused as to how to proceed.

Comment: You cannot have 2 responses from one request. It is request-response. 1 to 1.

Comment: This is sort if what I guessed. I think there must be a new query to get the updated response code